# Can I use same Admob Account for different Google play developers account?

Tags: admob, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

currently I am having One Google play account for games and apps.I am planning to create new google play account which will consist of only games and my old account will hold the apps.But I want to use single admob account for both google play accounts,so that revenue generated by both games and apps will be at same place.

In short,Can I use same Admob Account for different Google play developers account?
is it legal?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-have-two-Google-Developer-accounts-both-having-apps-monetized-by-a-single-AdMob-publisher-ID), It is possible two have two Google Play Accounts that are linked in one Admob Account. You can also check this related [question](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-multiple-users-AdMob-IDs-in-one-Google-Play-developers-account).

Answer (score 0):

It’s risky. Saying from experience,  Google may ban both of your accounts. So you better don’t do it. Be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. For your reference, I am attaching a google support thread here.

https://support.google.com/admob/thread/28633276/can-i-have-two-google-developer-accounts-both-having-apps-monetized-by-a-single-admob-publisher-id?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

absolutely yes!

it's okay to use multi google play accounts with one Admob account.

Comment: It would be nice if you add an example or an useful links to your answer instead writing it in a single line.

Comment: Please cite some citations or proof that it is possible to do so.